# Swift optional binding and SKNode.name

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, option-type, sknode

Is there a better way to write the code where I get the name of each SKNode, it just seems a bit long winded.

```
// eachChild is an SKNode
for eachChild in children {
    var theActualChildName: String
    if let childName = eachChild.name {
        theActualChildName = childName
    } else {
        theActualChildName = "Undefined"
    }
    println("NODE NAME = \(theActualChildName)")
}
```

I could write, (see below) which works even if there is no name, but if feels bad as its force unwrapping an optional.

```
// eachChild is an SKNode
for eachChild in children {
    println("NODE NAME = \(eachChild.name!)")
}
```

I know Swift is all about safety, but it just feels like I am getting bogged down in code and was wondering if there is something I am missing?

**EDIT:**
I have noticed that even though `SKNode.name` is a String? if you force unwrap it and it has no value it returns and empty String `""`, I was thinking it would return nil.

**EDIT2:**
Just to note that the answer by Antonio is indeed what I was after, but in the case of `SKNode.name` when the node is coming from an `scene.SKS` file it seems that even though no name is specified the node still gets the name `""` (Empty string). If you run the code:

```
let childName = eachChild.name ?? "Undefined"
```

You will either get the given `"Name"` or `""`, you will never get `"Undefined"` If you set `eachChild.name = nil` and run the code above you will get `"Undefined"` I am assuming that the name property is getting set to "" in the `*.sks` file if no other value is specified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I presume that `name` is an optional field - you can use the [nil coalescing operator](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH6-XID_123):

```
let actualChildName = eachChild.name ?? "Undefined"
```

Comment: Yup, seems the best way. (And, for example, you might combine this with more functional operations—to build an array of the names, you only need a one-liner: `let namesArray = children.map { $0.name ?? "Undefined" }`)

Comment: Yeah good usage of `map`. Endless things can be done with just 3 methods: `map`, `filter` and `reduce` :)

Comment: Much appreciated Antonio, thats just what I was after.